# Character Escape in Cmake and make is different

Tags: cmake, makefile, protocol-buffers

#### Background

I have a C++ project using CMAKE 3.18, and it works well. This project depends on protobuf 3.17 by source. For some reasons, I want to degrade the protobuf 3.17 to 3.5.2. I just modify the version of protobuf I want to use in `FindProtoBuf.cmake`:

```
    FetchContent_Declare(
            protobuf
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
            GIT_TAG b5fbb742af122b565925987e65c08957739976a7 #3.5.2
    )
```

Then I got compiling error:

```
ir/CMakeFiles/lib_ir_proto.dir/build.make:79: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

I open this file, and find the line in `lib_ir_proto.dir/build.make`:

```
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: ir/protobuf::protoc
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: ../ir/proto/data_type.proto
```

It seems make cannot figure out `::`. I change the `build.make` manually and the compiling goes on and broke on another place of having `protobuf::protoc`. There are many places using it so I can't change it one by one.

```
# mannualy change
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: ir/protobuf\:\:protoc
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: ../ir/proto/data_type.proto
```

`protobuf::protoc` is a cmake target produced by protobuf's official compiling cmakelist, I use it in `FindProtobuf.cmake`  this way:

```
    set(PROTOC_EXE protobuf::protoc)
```

And then this compiler was used to compile proto files.

I tried to escape in CMake：

```
set(PROTOC_EXE protobuf\\:\\:protoc)
```

But still get error with the same line of `lib_ir_proto.dir/build.make`:

```
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: ir/protobuf/:/:protoc
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: ../ir/proto/data_type.proto
```

make file doesn't have a `\` escaping backslash as I wanted. Does anyone has some suggestions?

PS:
With higher protobuf, It all goes well.The generated make file:

```
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: _deps/protobuf-build/protoc-3.17.0.0
ir/proto/data_type.pb.cc: ../ir/proto/data_type.proto
```

The right `ptoroc` was found.It seems in lower protobuf, protoc target change?

Comment: Looks like there is no `protobuf::protoc` target in the Protobuf 3.5.2. Compare current [cmake/protoc.cmake](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/cmake/protoc.cmake) and [the one](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v3.5.2/cmake/protoc.cmake) with 3.5.2 tag. Actually, `protobuf::protoc` is a synonim (ALIAS) for `protoc` target, so you could use the latter one in your code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Really thanks. I tried, And it succeeded. Thank you!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hello, I have another question. Now I compiled, but I got an error with enum type. In 3.17, `Enum_name` method can be used to get a generated enum type name. But There is no this method in 3.5.2. DO you know how to get enum name in 3.5.2?

Comment: Sorry, I am no an expert in *using* protobuf library.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, `protobuf::protoc` is just an alias of `protoc`. So just use `protoc` target name in CMakeLists.txt is ok.